# datapcker, DAYNAME in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two input box one with a datapicker and the other is textbox

```html
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>DAYNAME: <input type="text" id="DAYNAME"></p>
```

I want that when users select dates from datapicker, DAYNAME will appear in DAYNAME textbox

Comment: 1) What datepicker library are you using? 2) Where is your JS code? SO is not a code writing service 3) What language should the day names be in? Presumably English?

Comment: jquery dtapicker day name in swedish

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI datepicker comes with `formatDate` .

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(index, item) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var dayName = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date);
      $('#DAYNAME').val(dayName );
    }
  });
```